# pandas - reshape dataframe to edge list according to column values

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

Starting from this simple dataframe:

```
  node   t1   t2
0    a  pos  neg
1    b  neg  neg
2    c  neg  neg
3    d  pos  neg
4    e  neg  pos
5    f  pos  neg
6    g  neg  pos
```

I would like to build an edgelist file to read it as a undirected network. The expected output is:

```
b c
a d
a f
d f
e g
```

So basically I'm linking two nodes if they have the same pair of values in the `['t1','t2']` columns. So far I tried first to group the values into one new column:

```
d['c'] = [tuple(i) for i in df[['t1','t2']].values]
```

But then I'm stucked in grouping the users as I wish.

EDIT:
fix error in the creation of the new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'node': ['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
               't1': ['pos', 'neg', 'neg', 'pos', 'neg', 'pos', 'neg'],
               't2': ['neg', 'neg', 'neg', 'neg', 'pos', 'neg', 'pos']})

K = nx.Graph()
K.add_nodes_from(df['node'].values)

# Create edges
for i, group in df.groupby(['t1', 't2'])['node']:
    # generate all combinations without replacement 
    # from the group of similar column pairs
    for u, v in itertools.combinations(group, 2):           
        K.add_edge(u, v)

print(K.edges())
```

> Result: [('a', 'd'), ('a', 'f'), ('c', 'b'), ('e', 'g'), ('d', 'f')]

The trick here is to group by the 2 columns at the same time in pandas. Then, you can just create all combinations of edges to add in the graph.